# afterUpdate event hook, transactions, and old state in consecutive requests

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm

We're running into a weird issue where objects are created in a first request, but they are not returned in a second request.
Let's assume we have two domain classes:

```
Class A {
    static hasMany = [bs: B]

    def afterUpdate() {
        this.addToBs(new B(a: this))
        this.save()
    }
}

Class B {
    static belongsTo = [a: A]
}
```

When a put is sent on an instance of A via `PUT /as/<id>`, `update()` is invoked in the `RestfulController` which is annotated with `@Transactional`.

What we can observe is, that every once in a while a follow-up request send by the API consumer after the response of the first request is returned, `GET /bs` does not return the new instance of B which should have been created in the first request and is also returned on further requests.

I'd expected that grails only sends the response to the API consumer once the transaction is committed, which would mean that the next request should see all changes from that transaction, shouldn't it?

What could be the reason for that behavior? Is the transaction committed after the grails app already sent the response to the API consumer? If so, is the reason the `@Transactional` around the `update()` which is turned on by default?

I know in this example the code in `afterUpdate` could probably also be put into `beforeUpdate`, but I just tried to to simplify the example as far as I could.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, code in `afterUpdate()` and the like are not included in the transaction. You'd have to create a transaction explicitly (and maybe a session too). See http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html

I advise against GORM updates within `afterUpdate()` and friends because it leads to weird issues like this, and makes it difficult to unit test the domain models. If you delegate saving to a transactional service instead, not only would it just work, you'd also be able to confirm it with integration tests.

In my Grails apps, I keep my controllers really dumb:

1. Call a service
2. Return the service's output (possibly formatting it).

I keep all business logic in services because controllers are kind of a pain to test well. Here's an example:

```
@grails.transaction.Transactional
class SomeService {
    def saveA(A a) {
        // This method will run in a transaction.
        a.addToBs(new B(a: this))
        a.save()
    }
}
```

And in the controller...

```
class SomeController {
    def update() {
        ...
        someService.save(a)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that advice Emmanuel. I thought maybe it's still possible to use those hooks properly, but I'll check out putting the operation into a service.

Comment: You can use those hooks, but you'll need to wrap the GORM usage within either a new session or transaction (I don't remember which one) using `DomainClass.withSession()` or `DomainClass.withTransaction()`, respectively. The problem is the hooks execute outside of @transaction.